# is there easier way to increase EBS size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

the steps showed in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/console-modify.html
are very complex.

Basically to resize EBS, I need to:

1. modify volumn size
2. expand partition

   2-1. detach root device from original EC2 and attach it to another EC2

   2-2. login another EC2:
      sudo umount /
      sudo parted /dev/xvda

   (parted) unit s

   (parted) print

   'Ignore' to all questions

   (parted) rm 1
       ......
       sudo e2fsck -f /dev/xvda1

   2-3.To return an expanded root partition to its original instance:
   Detach the expanded partition from its secondary instance
   Reattach the volume to the primary instance using the device name that you identified: /dev/xvda

   Start the primary instance.

   Terminate the second EC2
3. Extend linux FS:

   sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1

   df -h to see the result

is there easy and safe way to expand EBS size?

-------- update with more information

My EC2 is ubuntu 16.04

```
~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  200G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0  100G  0 part /
```

based on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html and my lsblk output, I need to expand partition. then based on #5 and #6 of http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/expand-linux-partition.html, I need to detach then attache the partition from the original EC2. and then based on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-detaching-volume.html, I need to first umount -d /dev/xvda, detach partition from original EC2, then attach it to a new EC2, expand partition using parted....

Answer (score 2):

If the EBS volume is your boot volume and you are using Amazon Linux, then you simply need to:

- Modify the volume size (eg in the console)
- Reboot the instance

Code that runs at startup will automatically expand the partition to use the new space available.

If you do not wish to reboot the instance, follow the directions on [Extending a Linux File System after Resizing the Volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html). These instructions do not list the need to unmount/reattach the volume.

Comment: Hi, John Rotenstein, mine is ubuntu 16.4, will reboot work? in fact I have stopped and then started it (will that be the same as reboot?), run "lsblk" still get the above output (see my update of the original post). if I follow your link, it eventually said I need partition, detach volume, umount, etc.(see my update)

Comment: The "resize on reboot" ability is a function of Amazon Linux. It probably isn't implemented in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

### Now login through putty and follow the below mention steps -

- ```
   1. mount -o size=10M,rw,nodev,nosuid -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp
  ```

2. lsblk
   3. sudo file -s /dev/xvd*
   4. sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
   5. sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
   6. df -h

Comment: Vikram: Got it. Thanks.